# Project Layout and Site Structure in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, project-layout

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and would like to create and deploy a website using ASP.NET MVC.

I have a few old sites that run classic ASP and the site-structure goes like this:

- web.root (holds website pages)
- data.files (holds databases)
- log.files (log files)

I was wondering if the same structure is used for ASP.NET MVC??

What’s the best practice for storing your Visual Studio project files?

Comment: Just a point to note.  If you're deploying ASP.NET MVC apps, you'll save yourself a lot of hassle by using IIS7.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not an option so I've changed my global.asax file and added the .aspx extension to my controller route to work on IIS6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC uses its own structure. There are excellent books on how ASP.NET MVC works, including [Professional ASP.NET MVC 1.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470384611) by Wrox.  Understanding *why* ASP.NET MVC differs from ASP.NET and *why* it does what it does is **crucial** to utilizing it correctly.

MVC [uses its own file structure](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part1.htm), as I alluded to before:

[image: Image File Structure]

This file structure is 'by default' or as MVC-types call it, "[Convention over configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration)".  If you install Visual Studio 2008, and start a new ASP.NET MVC 1.0 project, you'll find that this structure has been created for you.

With regards to deployment, [there are plenty of Stack Overflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[asp.net-mvc]+deployment) that deal with that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I understand that MVC uses it own file structure but when you deploy your site how should you set up your directories on the server.

Do you just deploy the site to your web.root folder and point IIS there?

Comment: @Jemes When you hit 'Publish' Visual Studio takes care of this for you.

Comment: Thanks George, I'll check that out.

Answer (score 0):

**Saving your project files**

Use source control for this, for example, SVN. You can read more about [SVN here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464417/how-to-use-svn-branch-tag-trunk).

**Deploying the application**

There are built in deployment functionallity in Visual Studio which lets you deploy the web-project to Local Folder, FTP or IIS. You can read more about [Site Deployment here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178610(VS.80).aspx).

**Understanding ASP.NET MVC**

For this you should visit the ASP.NET MVC Video section on [asp.net/learn/](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc-videos/)